# Adding multiple images to DragView

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a card game(Patience/solitaire/klondike) in which I'm using JavaFX's drag and drop features. To show a ghost image of the card I'm dragging I use the Dragboard.

```
Dragboard db;
db.setDragView(source.getImage());
```

This all works fine as it should but I can't figure out how I could tackle the dragging of whole stacks.(Multiple cards layered over eachother with only the top of each card visible) Each stack of cards is stored in an arraylist but since I can only add 1 image to the dragboard at a time, I'm stuck.

So the quick question:

1. Is there a way to add multiple images to a dragboard?
2. Or is it
       possible to achieve this same effect in another way?
3. Or is it possible to create 1 Image object out of multiple Image objects to
      place this new Image on the dragboard?

The dragDetected eventhandler:

```
    /*
    On dragDetected check the source of the event, copy to clipboard and show a ghost image
 */
private void dragDetected(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    Dragboard db;
    ClipboardContent cc;


    if(mouseEvent.getSource() instanceof CardPane){
        CardPane source = (CardPane) mouseEvent.getSource();
        cc = new ClipboardContent();
        db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);

        if(source.getCard() != null) {
            //IF from stacks or nextCards
            if (stacks.contains(source) || nextCards.contains(source)) {
                db.setDragView(source.getCard().getImage());
                cc.putString(String.valueOf(source.getCard().getNumber()));
            } else {
                //PLACE MULTIPLE IMAGES TO THE DRAGBOARD HERE
            }

            db.setContent(cc);
            source.setVisible(false);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Create an `ImageView` out of each image, add the image views to some appropriate pane, and [snapshot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) the pane to get an image.

Comment: Wow, I actually got that working. Brilliant solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll share my updated code here in case anyone ever finds themselves in a similar situation.

I was able to find a solution to this thanks to @James_D

For every element I want to add to the picture, I create a new ImageView, add it to a Pane and position it correctly.

Once all elements are added, I snapshot the Pane and use the Image that I get back as my Dragboard Image.

My new drag detected code:

```
    private void dragDetected(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    Dragboard db;
    ClipboardContent cc;


    if(mouseEvent.getSource() instanceof CardPane){
        CardPane source = (CardPane) mouseEvent.getSource();
        cc = new ClipboardContent();
        db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);

        if(source.getCard() != null) {
            //IF from stacks or nextCards
            if (stacks.contains(source) || nextCards.contains(source)) {
                db.setDragView(source.getCard().getImage());
                cc.putString(String.valueOf(source.getCard().getNumber()));
            } else {
                //PLACE MULTIPLE IMAGES TO THE DRAGBOARD HERE
                Pane stackImagePane = new Pane();
                Optional<List<CardPane>> stackListOptional = cards.stream()
                                                    .filter(list -> list.stream()
                                                    .anyMatch(e -> e.equals(source))
                                                    )
                                                    .findFirst();

                if(stackListOptional.isPresent()){
                    ArrayList<CardPane> stackList = (ArrayList) stackListOptional.get();

                    double y = 0;
                    for (CardPane e : stackList) {
                        ImageView view = new ImageView(e.getImage());
                        view.setY(y);
                        y += 20;
                        stackImagePane.getChildren().add(view);
                    }

                    Image ghostStack = stackImagePane.snapshot(null,null);
                    db.setDragView(ghostStack);
                    cc.putString(String.valueOf(source.getCard().getNumber()));
                }

            }

            db.setContent(cc);
            source.setVisible(false);
        }
    }


}
```